# Skiasharp loan image from URL and draw on Canvas in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I was looking for a way to load image from URL and draw in on a SKCanvas using Skiasharp in Xamarin.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/97717/skiasharp-get-skbitmap-from-url

I found the link above but somehow my program crashed usng the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking around the internet I finally made the code to work. Below is my code with a bit more of something such as first check if the file exists in the URL, and also to resize the image to fit the whole canvas size.

```
HttpWebResponse response = null;
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "HEAD";
request.Timeout = 2000; // miliseconds

try 
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) //Make sure the URL is not empty and the image is there
    {
        // download the bytes
        byte[] stream = null;
        using(var webClient = new WebClient()) 
        {
            stream = webClient.DownloadData(url);
        }

        // decode the bitmap stream
        resourceBitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(stream);

        if (resourceBitmap != null) 
        {
            var resizedBitmap = resourceBitmap.Resize(info, SKFilterQuality.High); //Resize to the canvas
            canvas.DrawBitmap(resizedBitmap, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex) 
{

}
finally 
{
    // Don't forget to close your response.
    if (response != null) 
    {
        response.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FFImageLoading` library, it support putting `Image Source` to `url` out of the box. it uses SkiaSharp to render images.
Or if you're feeling adventurous, you can always look that the implementation in the source code and create a custom one to suit your need  [here](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading)